# I need help calculating two Access form text-boxes together when form opens

Tags: forms, ms-access, textbox, sum

I have a form that has two textboxes showing two different totals. I have a third textbox that needs to have the sum of both textbox 1 and 2. I have tried different things in the control source that I have seen in other forums but they arent working for me. Ive tried using "IIF" and different functions but it just ends up being zero or showing nothing.
These are the names:
[TXTSUM]=[TXT1]+[TXT2]

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `=[TXT1]+[TXT2]`, you do not need to declare the name of the text box you are currently editing the control source for.

Comment: Arithmetic with Null results in Null. If you want a value to show if either field is Null, handle Null with Nz() function: `=Nz([TXT1],0) + Nz([TXT2],0)`